# How can I get tesseract-ocr v5 to find the eng.traineddata file?

Tags: scanner, ocr, tesseract

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
tesseract 5.3.2
XSane 0.999
YAGF 0.9.5
Epson Workforce WF-4835 printer/scanner

This set up works together to a point. Clicking the **Scan** button in YAGF causes XSane to start up, scan the document in the scanner, and display the scan in the left window of YAGF. But when I click the **Recognize** button in YAGF, no text appears in the right-hand window and an error message says that the `eng.traineddata` file cannot be found.

The location is defined in these ways:

- In the **YAGF Settings** > **OCR and Languages**, **Path to Tesseract Data Files** is defined as `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5/tessdata/`.
- `$ sudo export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5/tessdata/`
- The following lines were added to the `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_rc`, and `~/.bash_profile` files: `export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5/tessdata/`

Can anybody suggest why YAGF/tesseract can't find the `eng.traineddata` file, hiding in plain sight?

Comment: Try setting Path to Tesseract Data Files to `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5` rather than `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5/tesseract`. AFAIK you can't run shell builtins like `export` with sudo.